# How do I iterate over entire dictionary keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

Diction is a dictionary containing keys and values. I want to iterate over dictionary keys in which I will return an array of keys with values less than or equal to 20. But, I am only iterating over one key. How do I iterate over the entire dictionary keys?

```
def total(diction):
    for key in diction:
        if diction[key] <= 20:
            return [key]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function finishes execution when it hits the first `return` statement.

You can adjust your function like this.

```
def total(diction):
    result = []
    for key, value in diction.items():
        if value <= 20:
            result.append(key)
    return result
```

This function appends the keys satisfying your criterion to a list and only returns that list once it has looked at all (key, value) pairs in the `dict`.

Alternatively, you can write a generator function:

```
def total_gen(diction):        
    for key, value in diction.items():
        if value <= 20:
            yield key
```

You might consider giving the functions a better name than `total` and have them take an additional parameter (for example named `limit`) in order avoid hardcoding the value `20`.

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'a': 5, 'b': 100, 'c': 23, 'd': -2}
>>> total(d)
>>> ['d', 'a']
>>> list(total_gen(d))
>>> ['d', 'a']
```

Of course, you could also use succinct list or generator expressions:

```
>>> [key for key, value in d.items() if value <= 20]
>>> ['d', 'a']
>>> 
>>> for k in (key for key, value in d.items() if value <= 20):
...:    print(k)
...:    
d
a
```

The generator-function and the generator expression are especially useful in cases where you don't need all the keys in memory at once - for example if you just want to iterate over them.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the dict items with a list comprehension like this:

```
def total(diction):
    return [key for key, value in diction.items() if value <= 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def total(diction):
    result = []
    for key in diction:
        if diction[key] <= 20:
            result.append(key)
    return result
```

Or using a list comprehension

```
def total(diction):
    return [key for key in diction if diction[key] <= 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the keys to a list, then only return after you have gone through all the keys.

```
def total(diction):
    key_list = []
    for key in diction:
        if diction[key] <= 20:
            key_list.append(key)
    return key_list
```

This could also be done with list comprehension:

```
def total(diction):
    return [k for k in diction if diction[k]<=20]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure if I understood your question correctly. But you can get a list of keys of a dictionary object with ".keys()"  attribute of a dictionary. E.g. if you have a dictionary object named "diction" then with diction.keys() you get a list object with keys as list item in it. Then you can iterate through each keys like that:

For dict_key in diction.keys():
    diction[dict_key] = ......

Hope, it helps

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'iterating over one key'? You are indeed iterating over all the keys when you write this, one at a time -

```
for key in diction:
```

If you want to do that in a single line, you could use a lambda function to shorten the code -

```
list(filter(lambda x: dic[x]<=20, dic.keys()))
```

Although, even here you check the keys one at a time. That's iteration!!